# Generalize Oddtown

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Suppose we have a city with $n$ people. In this city there are $m$ clubs. The number of members in each club is not divisible by $s$ (for a given $s$), but the number of people in the intersection of each two clubs is. Show that $m<cn$, where $c$ is the number of (distinct) primes that divide $s$.

My ideas so far: I can solve this when $s=p^k$ for $p$ prime. In this case, consider the n-coordinate vectors $v_1,v_2..v_m$ such that the $j$ entry of $v_i$ is $1$ if the person number $j$ belongs to the club number $i$ and else it's $0$. If these vectors are LD over the rationals, they are also LD over the integers, ie, we can find integers $r_i$ such that $\sum_i r_i v_i=0$. We can assume that there is a $j$ such that $r_j$ is not a multiple of $p$, otherwise we divide everyone for $p$ until that happens. Taking inner product with $v_j$ we have $\sum_i r_i v_iv_j=0$. We have $p^k \mid r_iv_iv_j$ for all $i$ different from $j$, therefore $p^k\mid r_jv_jv_j$ which implies $p \mid r_j$, contradiction. So, the vectors are LI and $m\leq n$.

I think the general case will follow in a similar fashion, but for that we will need $cn$ coordinate vectors, and it's not obvious how to construct that.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_c$ be the distinct primes dividing into $s$, where $p_i$ occurs with multiplicity $m_i$.

For each $i\in \{1,\dots,p\}$, let $S_i$ be the set of clubs whose member sets are not a multiple of $p_i^{m_i}$. Your logic proves that $|S_i|\le n$, because $S_i$ is a collection of clubs where each has have a size which is not a multiple of $p_i^{m_i}$, but any two have an intersection whose size is a multiple of $s$, and therefore is a multiple of $p_i^{m_i}$.

Furthermore, every club must belong to one of the sets $S_i$; if a club were in none of the sets, then its size would be a multiple of $\mathrm{lcm}(p_1^{m_1},\dots,p_c^{m_n})=s$. Therefore, the total number of clubs is at most $\sum_i |S_i|=cn$.